# Looking for manga: Likeness percentage seen above characters

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m looking for manga: she was reincarnated or pulled in a book - but could see other peoples likeness gauge above their heads. If it fell below 0% she’d die. So she was trying to win favour with her brothers in order to survive( who were quite murderous at the beginning towards her but she noticed the percentage go up in the most surprising moments)

Comment: I'm at work and can't give a full answer right now, but maybe *Death is the Only Ending for the Villainess*? IIRC it hits basically every note you mentioned, but you can check out [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if it can jog your memory on any other possible details.

Comment: Yes! That’s it! Thank you so so much. I can’t believe you got it from such a lousy description:)) Thanks again Toki

Comment: @toki Could you post that as an answer so it can be voted on and Magdalena can formally accept it? Thanks.

Comment: @qazmlpok thanks for the ping, I'll get right on it. Totally slipped my mind.

Comment: @Magdalena - If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed in comments, this is [Death is the Only Ending for the Villainess/Villains Are Destined to Die](https://myanimelist.net/manga/133641/Villains_Are_Destined_to_Die). It is a Korean webtoon starring a university student who passes out trying to clear the hard route of a wildly popular Otome game, and wakes up as Penelope Eckhart, the main protagonist of that hard route.

The part where you mention she "could see other peoples likeness gauge above their heads" is the manifestation of a game mechanic, wherein she must raise the affections of those around her so she doesn't end up dying:

[image: 18% and 10% floating above two character's heads]

It is offered online in English through [Tapas](https://tapas.io/episode/1901076), and in its native Korean on [Kakao](https://page.kakao.com/home?seriesId=54845189).

Comment: just a note (not entirely sure if it's appropriate to put it in the answer), but there is no official English release for this, otherwise I would've supplemented with more screenshots -- but taking meaningful screenshots from an already illegally distributed work leaves a bad taste in my mouth, and my most direct source was missing a good chunk of the beginning chapters, so I left it alone.

Comment: It is licensed by Tapas under the name "Villains are destined to die".

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't listed under the External Links page on MAL, and Google searches for the name I knew it under gave no hits (obviously), so I just assumed there was no official English publisher. I'll edit that information in.